# VirtualBox Desktop Icon VM Fails Unless VBox GUI is Running

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, desktop

I created a CentOS 7 VM in VirtualBox 6.1.34 on Windows 10. This launches and works fine. I created a desktop shortcut by right-clicking the VM in the GUI, and that also works fine; the VM is launched when I double click it.

However, this is only true if the VirtualBox GUI is running. If I shut it down and try to launch the VM using the desktop icon, it starts the launch, then  freezes before it reaches the login screen. Graphical boot, so I'm not sure what stage of the boot is dying, but it seems to differ a bit each time. Also, VM is completely unresponsive; won't accept mouse or keyboard interaction at all and has to be forcibly powered off.

Is it required to have the VirtualBox GUI running in order to use desktop icons to launch VMs? This seems very odd if so.

Comment: If you wish a text based VM App try QEMU.

Comment: You might wish also to use VMware instead. You can run a VMware VM (VMDK) with the vmrun command. So you can do it either way.